# How to read XML document and append the values of it to combo boxes and textboxes

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mvvm

**EditingModel.cs:**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> color;
public ObservableCollection<string> Color
{
    get { return color; }
    set
    {
        color = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<string> shapes;
public ObservableCollection<string> Shapes
{
    get { return shapes; }
    set
    {
        shapes = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Shapes");
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<string> size;
public ObservableCollection<string> Size
{
    get { return size; }
    set
    {
        size = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Size");
    }
}
```

**EditingsViewModel.cs:**

```
private string selectedcolor;
public string SelectedColor
{
    get { return selectedcolor; }
    set
    {
        if (value != selectedcolor)
        {
            selectedcolor = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedColor");
        }
    }
}
private string selectedshapes;
public string SelectedShapes
{
    get { return selectedshapes; }
    set
    {
        if (value != selectedshapes)
        {
            selectedshapes = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedShapes");
        }
    }
}
private string selectedsize;
public string SelectedSize
{
    get { return selectedsize; }
    set
    {
        if (value != selectedsize)
        {
            selectedsize = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSize");
        }
    }
}
```

**XML document:** (name of the xml doc is EditingsValue.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MYEDITINGS[]>
<MYEDITINGS>
  <Group name="GeneralEditings">
     <EditingsName name="COLOR" value="red"/>
     <EditingsName name="SHAPES" value="circle"/>
     <EditingsName name="SIZE" value="medium"/>
     <EditingsName name="FILE PATH" value="C:\ProgramFiles"/>
  </Group>
</MYEDITINGS>
```

**EditingsView.xaml:**

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedColor,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" Width="150"    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding Color}"/ >
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedShapes,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" Width="150"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}"/ >
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSize,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" Width="150"    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding Size}" />
<TextBox     Height="26"  Grid.Column="3"  IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="150"   Text="{Binding ElementName=Mygroups, Path=DataContext.FolderPath,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
<Button   KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"  Grid.Column="4"  Content="Browse"    Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"   MinWidth="45"   Command="{Binding  ElementName=Mygeoups,Path=DataContext.FolderCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

In my above code,I'm setting default value for my combo box using **SelectedIndex**,and then allowing the users to select their own value. Then I'm writing the selected values of user in **XML document** as mentioned above. Upto this everything is working fine.
But now my requirement is, if I open my application again,I should not get the default values in the combo boxes and textboxes, instead I should read the xml document and display the values of that in my combo boxes and textboxes.

How to achieve this using MVVM (wpf). 
 Can any one help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this one help to you

For the **EditingsViewModel.cs** Constructor Read the Xml File, Assign the Values to Model

```
  public EditingsViewModel()
    {
           ComboBoxModel = new EditingModel();

        //Xml Path
        string xmlpath = @"D:\MyDocument.xml";

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlpath);
        XmlNode colorNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/MYEDITINGS/Group/EditingsName[@name = 'COLOR']/@value");
        XmlNode shapesNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/MYEDITINGS/Group/EditingsName[@name = 'SHAPES']/@value");
        XmlNode sizeNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/MYEDITINGS/Group/EditingsName[@name = 'SIZE']/@value");
        XmlNode filePathNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/MYEDITINGS/Group/EditingsName[@name = 'FILE PATH']/@value");

        //Binding the Color to the Color Property
        var observableColors = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>() { "red","yellow","green"};
        ComboBoxModel.Color = observableColors;

        //Binding the Shapes to the Shape Property
        var observableShapes = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>() { "circle", "Triangle", "Rectangle" };
        ComboBoxModel.Shapes = observableShapes;

        //Binding the Size to the Size Property
        var observableSize = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>() { "medium", "high", "low" };
        ComboBoxModel.Size = observableSize;

        //Assign the Color Default vlaue from the Xml Document 
        SelectedColor = colorNode.Value;

        //Assign the Shape Default vlaue from the Xml Document 
        SelectedShapes = shapesNode.Value;

        //Assign the Size  Default vlaue from the Xml Document 
        SelectedSize = sizeNode.Value;

        //Assign the FilePath Default vlaue from the Xml Document 
        FolderPath = filePathNode.Value;
    }
```

**EditingsView.xaml** - Remove the Selected Index Property

```
   <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedColor,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" Width="150"    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxModel.Color}"/>
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedShapes,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" Width="150"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxModel.Shapes}"/>
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSize,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" Width="150"    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxModel.Size}" />
    <TextBox Name="Mygroups"    Height="26"  Grid.Column="3"  IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="150"   Text="{Binding ElementName=Mygroups, Path=DataContext.FolderPath,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
    <Button   KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"  Grid.Column="4"  Content="Browse"    Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"   MinWidth="45"   Command="{Binding  ElementName=Mygeoups,Path=DataContext.FolderCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: Where should I write  these codes in my project which is under this particular line "For this is the De-Serialize Model" ?  @ Saravanakumar Natarajan

Comment: U mean in ViewModel.cs??

Comment: Create Class for that model or Inside the View Model class you can use it.

Comment: @DSPT, I'm Modified this answer check it now

Comment: @ Saravanakumar Natarajan "ComboBoxModel = new Model()" what did  this particular line mean?

Comment: because it is showing me error ,if I include mymodelname=new model() in my ViewModel.cs

Comment: @ Saravanakumar Natarajan Please do me a favor. Mydocument,MydocumentName etc etc... is confusing me a lot, so I have edited my question with my view,viewmodel,xml document ,model names...Will you please edit your answer accordingly? so that I ll come out of confusion..Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DSPT, I'm modified the answer and myDocument.Group.MydocumentName.Value - > this line is used to get the value from  De serialize model.

Comment: I have edited xml document also...Have u edited that aslo? @Saravanakumar Natarajan

Comment: @DSPT, I'm edited xml doc also, only removing the Selected Index Property

Comment: @ Saravanakumar Natarajan Then where does MYDOCUMENT word comes from...because I didn't use the word MYDOCUMENT in my xml doc

Comment: oh!! you modified xml. Ok Xml file reading different ways That one of the ways is de serialize based on the model. One more ways is based on the attribute you read the value. If the color value having only one right?. Wait I will modify the answer

Comment: @ Saravanakumar Natarajan Yeah....I got it for one of my combo boxes, but I have two more combo boxes and one textbox ....I will edit my question accordingly....will u please help me by editing your answer according to my question?..Thanks in Advance..

Comment: @ Saravanakumar Natarajan I have edited my code....Please Please help me....Its urgent

Comment: @DSPt, Check Answer I Modified.